# find subset between date ranges considering weekdays in php

Tags: php, date, subset

what I actually looking for exact solution , that is given below with an 
example:

I need each subset of given date ranges depending on weekday

 
Example : 

I have start date(2015-09-29) and end date (2015-11-01) of an availability period (i.e, booking ).

I have multiple  checkin day and multiple  checkout day and day interval is 7 for that period:

like 
1. sunday to sunday
2. tuesday to tuesday
3. friday to friday

So the query in simple language is :

for 2015-09-29 to 2015-11-01 period , how can I get subset which will be based on above checkin / checkout

```
 
 array(
        0 => array ('2015-09-29','2015-10-06')  // for tuesday to tuesday [first subset]
        1 => array ('2015-10-04','2015-10-11')  // sunday to sunday [first sunday]
        2 => array ('2015-10-02',2015-10-09)    // for friday to friday [first friday]
        3 => array ('2015-10-11',2015-10-18)    // for sunday to sunday [second sunday]
        3 => array ('2015-10-06',2015-10-13)    // for tueday to tuesday [second tuesday]
        so on ...    
    )
```

Thnx for any advice / suggestion in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) for this.

Here is an working example to get you going:

```
function getRanges($start, $end, $weekdays) {
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = (new DateTime($end))->modify('-6 days');
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    $ranges = [];
    foreach($period as $day) {
        if(in_array($day->format('w'), $weekdays)) {
            $ranges[] = [
                $day->format('Y-m-d'),
                $day->modify('+7 days')->format('Y-m-d')
            ];
        }
    }
    return $ranges;
}

$start = '2015-09-29';
$end = '2015-11-01';
$weekdays = [0,2,5]; // 0 = sunday, 1 = monday ...
$ranges = getRanges($start, $end, $weekdays);
```